# javascript debugging in IE7?

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

I run Win XP in virtual box with IE7 for debugging sites that have to work in IE7.
I only have issues in IE7, not IE8, IE9, Firefox or Chrome.
How would I find what JS file IE is talking about when JS error happens?

I know about: "**IE Dev Toolbar**"  - but it doesn't give you this information either.

Here are the errors that I get in IE7 there are 3 errors:

```
Line 67 char 3(Expected identifier, string or number)
Line 4012 char 9 (Object doesn't support this property method)
Line 4065 char 9 (Object doesn't support this property method)
```

Actual html when saved as file only has 270 lines. 
So  - errors gotta be in external JS files.
I now there are other questions like this and I looked through them - but didn't find an answer to this question.

Comment: Can't you just use the developer tools in IE9, and set it to run in IE7 mode?

Comment: Thank you. Let me give it a try. I already have 3 virtual machines to run ie6, ie7 and ie8. Now it'll be 4-th one where there will have to be Vista/Win7 installed for single purpose of running IE9. :( hate microsoft.

Comment: @Andre IE8 has the same options in the developer tools - hit F12, the browser mode info is displayed at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the debugger that comes with Visual Studio - when you click on the error details in IE you will have an option to debug it with the VS Debugger.

Comment: Thanks. Does it need actual VS? Where would I get that thing?

Comment: @Andre [Try here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) or the [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22185)

Comment: @robertc: Thank you. Microsoft Script Debugger worked well. Also - one has to go to tools->options and check if "disable debug scripts" is unchecked. It was checked in my IE by default I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have an IE7 virtual machine; however, when it get's difficult to debug what's going on I've had good success being able to debug IE7 issues by using IE8 and setting it to "Compatibility View". There are [some differences, but they appear to be documented](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx).

Also, I know you are also able to set both the browser mode and document mode to IE7 and IE8 within IE9 (in addition to other debugging advancements), but since I have an IE8 virtual machine, I haven't felt compelled to do so, yet. But [here's a link](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx) that discusses that a bit more.